# Different output cache timeout for different usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I have several usercontrols which I would like to have a different output cache timeout.

I have tried the following but without success:

- Set cacheprofile (can apparently only be done on aspx pages).
- Do the following in codebehind:

  Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(OutputCaching.QuickTimeout))

  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)

  Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

  Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = true;

Apparently only `<%@ OutputCache Duration="6000" VaryByParam="" %>` works, but isn't there a way to take the duration from a config- or appsettings file?

Comment: Short answer is no. The documentation says cacheprofile is not supported in usercontrols

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible based on the **Remarks** of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) but is think that

> *HttpCacheability.Server* = *@ OutputCache*

instead of

> *HttpCacheability.Public*

Here is the doc for [HttpCacheability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability.aspx), this will help you pick the right choice for you.

Also I think it would be best if you put your code in the Page_Init or Page_PreInit like this:

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Me.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server)
    Me.Response.Cache.SetExpires(Date.Now.AddMinutes(10))
    Me.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(True)
    Me.Response.Cache.VaryByParams.IgnoreParams = True
End Sub
```

Regards,